# Need suggestion on the service oriented architecture

Tags: java, architecture, ejb, ejb-2.x, java1.4

We are a complete SOA workshop(Java only) and we use SOAP for the data transfer. Currently we are in a process of centralizing the database work for a specific component so the other components can fetch data from one application using SOAP.

My argument is that it is good to centralize but it adds a lot of latency when adding soap between database calls. I want a RMI/EJB type of implementation so we get serialized object and it reduces the marshaling overhead. I like the way the Ejbs are implemented and would like to use it. But the data that we return is not at all from one table, so, I cannot return a database table entity, the data might be from 20 other tables or more.

So, in our current system we have custom entities which are created to map to heavy sql queries. (not related to one table)

Can ejbs be used for this type of environment? If so, are there libraries that are readily available to map the result of a query to entities?

Unfortunately our in-house system is very old, we use java 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but it is going to be painful.  There was a reason EJB 3.0 entity beans were created.  It's because dealing with these sorts of complex requirements is really quite difficult to map via the old 2.x entity beans xml files.

If you are really building a new SOA layer to represent your database content, why would you do this with a technology that has been obsolete for almost 10 years?

Worse, building this with EJB 2.x and then using RMI/EJB will bind all of your other applications to this same outdated technology.  Very few people would choose to start a *new* EJB 2.1 project.

I honestly believe that you are better off using SOAP for your service instead of EJB, at least it won't couple you to an obsolete platform.  Current best practices prefer REST for entity transfer, and save SOAP for things RPC-style interactions, but there are lots of good libraries for doing your database tables to SOAP mappings, many of which are out-of-the-box for RDMS's.

Finally, if you are determined to do this, I'd suggest you first do a test.  Build a test framework to actually see if the SOAP deserialization is a significant cost component.  Compare it to the cost of the network transport.  Unless these entities are in the megabyte range, deserialization will be a tiny fraction of your overall application time.

Comment: When you mean `There was a reason EJB 3.0 entity beans were created. It's because dealing with these sorts of complex requirements` does it mean that the columns from more than 1 table be mapped to one enitity?